# React native expo - Reponse timed out

Tags: android, ios, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to run an app inside my Android emulator and on my Iphone using Expo and Create React Native App.

I' ve ran the following commands to do this.

```
create-react-native-app MyFirstApp

npm run android
```

After doing the run command the app runs in the emulator with the following error:

```
Something went wrong! Could not load *ip*. Network response timed out.

Uncaught error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out.
```

The same thing happens when I scan the QR code on my Iphone and I can't reach the ip in my web browser.

I've found the following fixes on internet but nothing seems to work:

- Add port 19000 to the inbound rules in Windows Firewall
- Update Java and npm
- npm start instead of npm run android

Edit:

I installed Expo XDE to start the server. It works fine when I use a tunnel but that option is extremely slow when reloading changes. It still doesn't work with localhost or LAN. Is it possible that I have to use something like port forwarding to open this port on my router?

Also: When I typ: localhost:19000 in Google Chrome I get some Json returned. But this doesn't work when I'm in Expo!

Comment: Why not just run `npm start`? does it work?

Comment: @Hardy I use run android because it automatically boots the app on my emulator. But npm start also doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed the problem! I just found the following solution:

Go to cmd and type ipconfig

get the ip4 adress of the virtual machine and copy it.

Than go to computer > properties > advanced system settings > environment variables and add the following system variable: REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME

As the value for the variable I had to paste the ip4 of the virtual machine.

Comment: I have similar kind of problem (with may a slight difference), but the solution doesn't work for me. I have posted details at: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47966887/expo-lan-configuration-doesnt-work-for-new-reactnative-project

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. My issue was that VirtualBox had installed a couple of virtual ethernet adapters and NPM was choosing one of those. After disabling those in Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Network Connections, the Expo app connected as expected.

Comment: I followed your solution and it worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Windows firewall blocks the request. You can define two inbound rules for Port 19000 and 19001

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the port by defining a .exprc file containing:

```
{
  "manifestPort": 8000
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue. I disable all other network adapter and left WIFI adapter enable. 
secondly you can also change the priority of adapter it also gonna work